# Prepending INTERFACE_SOURCES

Tags: c++, c, cmake, properties, target

I am looking to make an `INTERFACE` library, and specify `INTERFACE_SOURCES`
so that libraries that link against it also build these sources.

Unfortunately, due to some LTO issues, these sources need to be compiled and linked before the consumers' sources.

The `INTERFACE_SOURCES` property seems to append these sources to the consumer targets. Is it possible to prepend them instead?

I know that a workaround is to just set a sources variable and use that in the target but if possible I would like to use a target instead.

Answer (score 0):

The CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html) for `target_sources()` only supports **appending** sources to the list. One solution would be to get the `INTERFACE_SOURCES` list and use the [`PREPEND`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#prepend) list subcommand to prepend the sources to the list:

```
# Get the initial list of INTERFACE_SOURCES for the target.
get_target_property(INITIAL_TARGET_SOURCES MyLib INTERFACE_SOURCES)
message("INITIAL_TARGET_SOURCES: ${INITIAL_TARGET_SOURCES}")

# Prepend the additional INTERFACE target sources (TestClass2.cpp) to the list.
list(PREPEND INITIAL_TARGET_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/TestClass2.cpp)
# Set the INTERFACE_SOURCES to the updated list.
set_target_properties(MyLib PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_SOURCES "${INITIAL_TARGET_SOURCES}"
)

# Check that the target property was updated successfully.
get_target_property(UPDATED_TARGET_SOURCES MyLib INTERFACE_SOURCES)
message("UPDATED_TARGET_SOURCES: ${UPDATED_TARGET_SOURCES}")
```

Here, the initial list of `INTERFACE_SOURCES` contains only `TestClass1.cpp`, but after the `set_target_properties()` call, it contains `TestClass2.cpp;TestClass1.cpp`. Here is what gets printed:

```
INITIAL_TARGET_SOURCES: C:/workspace/testproj/TestClass1.cpp
UPDATED_TARGET_SOURCES: C:/workspace/testproj/TestClass2.cpp;C:/workspace/testproj/TestClass1.cpp
```

You can easily throw this into a CMake [`function`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/function.html) to avoid clutter, if you need to prepend sources at multiple locations within your CMake files.

Comment: I think I was misunderstood. I know how to prepend sources to the interface_sources property of a target. What I want is for the interface_sources to be prepend to the sources of the consuming target that links to the target with the interface_sources. As it is the INTERFACE_SOURCES are compiled and linked later than the consuming target's original sources.

Comment: @Veritas @Liarokapis Alexandros No code example was posted with the question, so it was difficult to understand the *specific* problem, and the *current* result vs the *desired* result. If you want to prepend the `INTERFACE_SOURCES` to the consuming target's sources, you can simply use the `list(PREPEND ...` as I've shown in my example to prepend to the consuming target's sources instead.

Comment: I am writing a Find module so I don't know the exact target that will be linked against the INTERFACE target. Otherwise this is trivial and INTERFACE_SOURCES are not even needed. I will try to improve the question, thanks a lot and sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: @Veritas Yes, if possible, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).